# ACF datepicker meta_query Compare Dates in m/d/Y g:i a - Not in Ymd Format

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, date-time

I'm looking for a way to use meta_query to filter out posts with a meta-key value of a date-time in `m/d/Y g:i a` format.

The post-meta is being set by ACF (Advanced Custom Fields).

I want to maintain `m/d/Y g:i a` formatting for output on the frontend, but also need to filter out posts with dates in the past.

I know that I can use `Ymd` format, likeso:

```
$date_now = date('Y/m/d');
  $args = [
    'meta_query'=>[
      'relation'=>'AND',
      [
        'key'=>'event_time',
        'value'=>$date_now,
        'compare'=>'>=',
        'type'=>'DATE',
      ],
  ]
];
```

I also know that I can retrieve all posts and use a subsequent loop to discard the posts which don't meet requirements.

But is there a better way to do this? 
Thanks for reading.

Comment: I would try using DATETIME based on the WP_Query custom field parameters. I know it requires MySQL format (YYYY-MM-DD) for "BETWEEN" comparison but since you're asking for all those dates greater than or equal to the date given it may work. Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should not be any need to do this.

Even if an ACF Field is using `'return_format' => 'm/d/Y g:i a',`

The post_meta value is in `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00` format.

```
$date_now = date('Y-m-d');
$args = [
  'meta_key'=>'the_date',
  'meta_value'=>$date_now.' 00:00:00',
  'meta_compare'=>'>=',
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

***Edit:*** I've noticed some discrepancies in this, the value may be in `Ymd`. When in doubt, check the data. You can find the post_meta by looking up the `post_id` in the `wp_postmeta` table.

Comment: i wasn't aware of the ACF field value.. thought it would return, what i want it to, but that is only considered in functions, i guess. probably makes sense to always store the same value and than modify it on demand. thanks for the hint.

Comment: and instead of looking up the table, you can always get the value of a custom field _wordpress style:_ `echo '<pre>' . print_r(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'FIELD_NAME'),1) . '</pre>';` aka the return value is Ymd, but Y-m-d was working fine, too.